# Voltage drops across capacitors

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

We generally see capacitor plates in questions denoted one as $+q$ and other $-q$. So according to formula $Q=CV$ we can say potential of the first plate is $+V$ and other $-V$ so the drop across the capacitor plates should $2V$ but we assume it to be $V$. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the notation. Typically there is a potential $V_+$, that denotes the potential of the **positively** charged conductor, and $V_-$,  that denotes the potential of the **negatively** charged conductor.

And $V$ in your formula refers to:

$$V = V_+ - V_-$$

Also, the following

> we can say potential of the first plate is $+V$
> and other $−V$

is actually not correct. There is no reason to think the potentials have the same magnitude. In fact, we are always free to choose the potential of one of the conductors to be $0$ and measure the potential of another conductor with the reference to the former.

Comment: Thankyou sir...

Comment: @A10thgrader if my answer fully resolves your confusion, consider upvoting and accepting it, please

Comment: Anyone knows the reason for a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your interpretation of the formula q=cv. In this formula V stands for the potential drop between the positive and negative plates and not the potential of each plate.In fact you cannot define the potential of each plate as such. We can only convey information about the potential difference between the two plates (V) which is given by the formula Q=CV.

Comment: Well, you could define the potential of either plate, simply by connecting it to a node at that potential.  But for the capacitor to have a certain charge, the potential of the other plate would then be defined by the potential difference, and the potential of the fixed-voltage plate.

Comment: Thankyou sir...